# ¿Cómo mejorar el caso base de una función recursiva en PHP?

Tags: php, php7, php5

Necesito una función que me retorne TODAS las urls de sitemaps que dentro contengan productos:

Hay sitemap que dentro contienen otros sitemap (comprimidos o no) y otros simplemente contienen productos o servicios (esto es lo que me interesa).

```
//Función recursiva que recibe un enlace y devuelve todos los sitemaps que contengan productos
$st = [];
function si_check($link)
{
    global $st;
    if(!$link) return $st;
    else{
        $xml = (array) getxml($link);
        if(conProductos($xml)) array_push($st, $link);
        else{
            foreach($xml as $e){
                si_check($e);
            }
        }
    }
}

function conProductos($xml)
{
    if(empty($xml["sitemap"])) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

**Aclaraciones:**

1- Se asume que un sitemap contiene servicios y productos cuando no contengan otros sitemaps dentro, esto se puede apreciar en la función `conProductos()`.

2- Si el sitemap está o no comprimido es indiferente para la función `getxml()`, ya que si lo tuviese lo descomprime antes de retornarlo.

3- No busco los enlaces de los productos o servicios en sí, sino los enlaces de los sitemaps que dentro contengan esos servicios y/o productos.

**Problemas:**

Mi problema es con el caso de base, como verán, actualmente es `if(!$link) return $st;` el cuál nunca se cumplirá, y aunque mi función no creo que sea infinita nunca me retornará el `$st`, así que me gustaría si me podes ayudar a determinar el caso base, de tal forma, que cuando se termine me retorné `$st`.

También considero que `$st`, debería pasarse como parámetro,pero al no tener casi experiencia con funciones recursivas prefiero ir a lo fácil.

Comment: Por favor, no preguntes varias veces lo mismo, puedes editar la pregunta original para mejorarla, no hace falta abrir otra. Las etiquetas [php7] y [php5] creo que sobra, pues la pregunta no tiene relación con una versión concreta.  Revisa el [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) para conocer el funcionamiento de SO.

Comment: @Fly, si me respondieran no habría necesidad de abrir nuevas preguntas. Eliminaré las anteriores.

Comment: Lo mismo no has planteado bien la pregunta, no hay nadie que sepa de esto o faltan datos. SI editas la pregunta con nuevo contenido se actualiza en la lista principal y los demás podrán ver que sale arriba, generando interés, quizá.

Comment: Deberías hacer (y mostrarnos) tres xml simples y mostrar los resultados obtenidos y los esperados. Es decir, un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Puedes ayudate de herramientas online de [php](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/) para que podamos probar el código u otras que faciliten las pruebas. Ni siquiera muestras un script operativo y sus datos de ejemplo, tan solo un par de funciones sueltas.

Comment: En esta pregunta, únicamente estoy preguntando algo muy concreto (el caso base de una función recursiva), también doy información de lo que quiero hacer como algo extra. Lo único que necesito ahora mismo es hacer que la función si_check() me retorne el array al finalizar, me parece innecesario aportar mil cosas para esta pregunta en concreto.

Comment: Como podrán apreciar, en la función recursiva si_check() hay dos casos, uno es cuando la función conProductos() retorna true: se añade el enlace a un array y cuando retorna false: se hace una llamada recursiva. Únicamente me hace falta retornar ese dato :/. Es como que yo pregunte ¿cuánto es 1 + 1? y me pregunten hasta mi fecha de nacimiento, no tiene sentido para mi. Abajo dejé aclaraciones sobre getxml(), etc. (es un simple file_get_contents con un strpos, que al detectar un ".gz" en la url hace un $content = gzdecode($content); y ya.

Comment: En tu caso, como usas una variable global, no hace falta que devuelvas ningún valor, llega con comprobar el valor del `$st` al finalizar la función.  Te sobra el  `if(!$link)...`  junto con su `else`. Al finalizar el `foreach` ya no habrá mas recursividades.

Comment: @Carlos Ese último comentario está fuera de lugar. Yo entré a tu pregunta, con la intención de ayudarte. Pero no la entendí, así que me fuí a responder otra que no necesitara mas tiempo en comprenderla que en responderla. Suscribo la petición de un ejemplo.